# opening pdf file using php

Tags: php

i wana open pdf file using php ,it works well but it prompt me for downloading that file in specified folder.. what i want to do is just by clicking a link pdf file get open without prompting for download.. anyone have idea about it?? thanx in advance.. below z the code

php code:

```
$mypdf = PDF_new();
PDF_open_file($mypdf, "");
PDF_begin_page($mypdf, 595, 842);
$myfont = PDF_findfont($mypdf, "Times-Roman", "host", 0);
PDF_setfont($mypdf, $myfont, 10);
PDF_show_xy($mypdf, "hello my first pdf converted file", 50, 750);
PDF_show_xy($mypdf, "Made with the PDF libraries for PHP.", 50, 730);


PDF_end_page($mypdf);
PDF_close($mypdf);

$mybuf = PDF_get_buffer($mypdf);
$mylen = strlen($mybuf);
header("Content-type: application/pdf");
header("Content-Length: $mylen");
header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=gen01.pdf");
print $mybuf;

PDF_delete($mypdf);

.....................................
html code:


<html>
<body>
Click here to see pdf file <a href="gen01.php" target="_blank">pdf1</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well, this will depend on the client browser (and also browser plugins). So you can't be sure it will display/open.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=gen01.pdf");`
But if the visitor doesn't have a PDF Reader associated with the 'application/pdf' mime-type, the browser WILL download the file.

Answer (score 0):

1.create a mysql table called fileHolder having the following attributes;

2.id, filename

3.then using HTML create the following form

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="1000000" />
<input type="file" required name="uploaded_file">
<input type=submit value=upload >
</form>
```

4.then create an upload.php using the following code

```
if ((!empty($_FILES["uploaded_file"])) && ($_FILES['uploaded_file']['error'] == 0)) {
//Check if the file is JPEG image and it's size is less than 350Kb
$filename = basename($_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
$ext = substr($filename, strrpos($filename, '.') + 1);
if (($ext == "pdf") && ($_FILES["uploaded_file"]["type"] == "application/pdf") &&
($_FILES["uploaded_file"]["size"] < 350000000)) {
 //Determine the path to which we want to save this file
 $newname = dirname(__FILE__) . '\\Abstract\\' . $filename;
    //Check if the file with the same name is already exists on the server
    if (!file_exists($newname)) {
        //Attempt to move the uploaded file to it's new place
        if ((move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $newname))) {
            echo "It's done! The file has been saved as: " . $newname;
        } else {
            echo "Error: A problem occurred during file upload!";
        }
    } else {
        echo "Error: File " . $_FILES["uploaded_file"]["name"] . " already exists";
    }
} else {
    echo "Error: Only .pdf images under 350MB are accepted for upload";
}
} else {
echo "Error: No file uploaded";
}
```

//========================================================
the above code is responsible for putting the file in a directory called abstract.

Finally we need to view the file on a browser. using the following

## query in a view.php file

//assuming you have the connection and select the db

```
header('Content-type: application/pdf');

select filename from fileHolder where id = 1;

if (empty($filename) && !empty($_GET['filename'])) /*file name comes from a link called 
$filename = $_GET['filename'];                     view which is used to identify the 
                                                    exact file that we are lookingfor*/
$filenames = "..\\user\\Abstract\\".$filename."";
$file = fopen($filenames, "r");
```

`enter code here`$fread = fread($file, filesize($filenames));
    echo $fread;